# Why does this linked example work in chrome but getScreenCMT is undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I'm aware of issues in chrome with getScreenCMT() reporting incorrectly also including [undefined](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10785) on mac, but I'm on windows chrome version 35.0.1916.153 m and [this svg drag example](http://www.codedread.com/dragtest.svg) ACTUALLY WORKS in my browser without error.

Here's my basic test code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="400" height="300" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
    <circle id="circle" fill="green" cx="100" cy="100" r="50"></circle>
    <script>
        console.log(document.documentElement.createSVGPoint);
        var testEl = document.getElementById('circle');
        console.log(testEl.getScreenCMT);
    </script>
</svg>
```

output:

> function createSVGPoint() { [native code] }
>
> undefined

Any idea why this is so?

Note: fwiw I've also tried similar from onload - everything else happens except getScreenCMT

UPDATE:
I've tried `console.log(ball.getScreenCMT)` from the above example before the mousedown() line `var m = ball.getScreenCMT()` and this also reports `undefined`, yet the example continues to function properly and I cannot coax out similar functionality - `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` .

Comment: Because the example uses getScreenCTM and not getScreenCMT

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'm going to keep this up here just to keep myself honest. :)